# How to avoid Pycharm (v2) Pyramid Debugging from stopping at files out from my project

Tags: debugging, pycharm, pyramid

Until Pycharm 2016.2, I was really satisfied with debugging session on my Pyramid App.

However since recently, when debugging, I got files - out from my project - opening and distracting me from my debugging session.

These files (among them) are :

- arbiter.py
- thread_util.py
- sync.py

How can I avoid this files to open on my Pycharm editor while debugging ?

Comment: Why they are opening? Do they have breakpoints?

Comment: Nope, no breakpoints on it, it is like they stay open few seconds and then the debugging flow of my app starts back.

Comment: I don't have an answer, only suggestions that might help. (1) Search for bug reports on JetBrains issue tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY  (2) Create a new fresh project in PyCharm and copy your current project into that one. (3) There might be a PyCharm log file that contains some information about why it includes the stray files.

Comment: If these come up when doing Step Into, there's a button for "Step Into My Code" which won't go off on a goose-chase in library code.

Comment: I proceeded to the following:
(1) upgraded to Pycharm 2.3
(2) checked the box "Do not step into library scripts" in Preferences/Debugging/Stepping
(3) rm -rf .idea and create a new project

However I still have these disturbing stops at files mentioned above